# открыть предыдущую страницу php

Tags: php

На сайте есть главная страница, куда попадают все авторизованные пользователи (main.php). Страница прогружается достаточно долго (ввиду своеобразного контента) и содержит ссылки на видео которые открываются на другой странице (play.php). Как возможно на странице play.php сделать ссылку, которая вернет пользователя обратно к main.php БЕЗ ПЕРЕЗАГРУЗКИ страницы?

Comment: технологии AJAX вам в помощь, перезаписывать содержимое страницы, раз вы хотите без перезагрузки страницы

Comment: рассмотрите вариант открытия `play.php` в модальном окошке без перехода на новую страницу. Ну или выясните, из за чего там долго грузится. Если сервер долго генерит страницу, то пробуйте ее кешировать. Если контент на странице тяжелый, то вопрос к ширине канала и кешированию на стороне клиента

Comment: По хорошему никак. просто не надо покидать эту страницу, весь ненужный контент можно спрятать javascript и подгрузить через ajax другое содержимое в какой нибудь div и в нем спокойно крутить ролики или что то еще

Comment: но ведь если вы нажмете на кнопку назад в браузере то страница появится! и без перезагрузки. это нужно сделать и мне...

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="button" onclick="history.back();" value="Назад"/>` оказалось все намного проще. В любом случае, спасибо за советы. Попробую модальное окно в версии 2.0

Comment: Если ваш ответ на ваш же вопрос является решением, отметьте его как принятый.